# Magento extend IsSaleable with custom stock value

Tags: magento, stock

I’m looking to accomplish the following. My shop only has products online which I actually have. I would like to add my suppliers stock to my site, so customers can see and buy the product, but they will receive notice about a delay in shipping.

I have used the shipping days option mentioned in this thread (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59143/P0/). This works perfectly.

I would like to extend this line.

`getData('days_to_ship')): ?>`

to

`getData('days_to_ship') && $_product->getData('bu_qty')>1):?>`

The attribute name bu_qty is the stock value of my supplier. I would like to use this value to specify if the product is available at my supplier or not. So, if I do not use this field (smaller than 1), the product is supposed to be Out of stock.

If I do use this bu_qty value and set is to the number 1 or higher with also the Days to ship it is supposed to show a message that the item is available for purchase and that it will ship in x days.

Anybody can help me out with this one ?

Comment: Might have better luck with this over at http://magento.stackexchange.com/